# speedometer gauge not updating all the values of live data

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I have a JSP program that gives output in JSON format. I want to update the `highchart` speedometer with that output. My gauge is taking only one value from the output. It is not getting updated further. But I am able to print the right values using alert statement. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
var chart1=new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart:{
                    renderTo:'container',
                    type:'gauge',
                    alignTicks:false
                },
                title:{
                    text:'Speedometer'
                },
                pane:[{
                    startAngle:-150,
                    endAngle:150,
                    size:350,
                    background:{
                    outerRadius:'105%',
                    innerRadius:'72%',
                        backgroundColor:{
                            radialGradient:{
                                cx:0.5,
                                cy:0.6,
                                r:1.0
                            },
                            stops:[
                                [0.3,'#A7A9A4'],
                                [0.45,'#DDD'],
                                [0.7,'#EBEDEA']
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
               {
                    startAngle:-150,
                    endAngle:150,
                    size:210
                }],
                yAxis:[{
                    min:0,
                    max:100,
                    minorTickInterval:'auto',
                    tickPixelInterval:70,
                    plotBands:[{
                        from:0,
                        to:50,
                        color:'green'
                    },{
                        from:50,
                        to:80,
                        color:'yellow'
                    },{
                        from:80,
                        to:100,
                        color:'red'
                    }],
                   pane:0
                },{
                    min:0,
                    max:220 ,
                    tickPosition:'inside',
                    minorTickPosition:'inside',
                    minorTickInterval:'auto',
                    tickPixelInterval:60,
                    plotBands:[{
                        from:0,
                        to:70,
                        color:'red'
                    },{
                        from:70,
                        to:130,
                        color:'yellow'
                    },{
                        from:130,
                        to:220,
                        color:'green'
                    }],
                    pane:1
                }],
                series:[{
                    data:[70],
                    name:'Speed',
                    tooltip:{
                        valueSuffix:' km/h'
                    },
                    dataLabels:{
                        formatter:function(){
                              if(this.point.realVal)
                                return this.y;    
                              }
                },
                    yAxis:0
                },{
                    data:[100],
                    name:'RPM',
                    dataLabels:{
                        formatter:function(){
                                if(this.point.realVal1)
                                return this.y;                                    
                        }
                    },
                          yAxis:1
                }]
},
    function (chart) {
           setInterval(function () {
                                     var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                                     point1=chart.series[1].points[0],
                                     newVal=[],newVal1=[],i,j;
                                 $.get('Db.jsp', null, function (tsv,state,xhr) {
                var data = eval ( '(' + xhr.responseText + ')' );
                                    for(i=0; i<data.points.length; i++){    
                                                                               $.each(data.points[i],function(key,val){
                                                    newVal.push(val);
                                    //alert(newVal);
                                    point.update(newVal);
                }
      }
     for(j=0; j<data.points.length; j++){   
                         $.each(data.values[j], function(key,val){
                                                       newVal1.push(val);
                                   //alert(newVal1);
                                   point1.update(newVal);
                                    }
                }
     });
  });
});
});
```

Comment: How your data looks like? var data = eval ( '(' + xhr.responseText + ')' ); ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Its a set of JSON arrays enclosed in a JSON object.

Comment: I'm aware how it is, but I asked if it is possible to paste "content" of this variable.

Comment: @SebastianBochan : This is the content of the variable.                  {"values":[{"a":"25000"},{"b":"36000"},{"c":"40"},{"d":"60"}],"points":[{"e":"47000"},{"f":"36000"},{"g":"470"},{"h":"10"}]}.. This is nothing but separate objects enclosed in arrays that are further enclosed in a single object.

Comment: You need to use numbers instead of strings, so it should be i.e "470" shoudl be replaced by 470 or use parseFloat() which "transofrm" string to number. Secondly you should have y variable instead of "b" or "c"....

Comment: @SebastianBochan : But one value is being displayed. i.e i am able to display 60 from "values" and 10 from "points". So I dont think that is the problem. Also I am able to display individual values if I give data.values[0] , data.values[1] etc instead of data.values[j]. The problem is with the updation of gauge. Help me on that please.

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Will calling chart.redraw() after every update solve the problem? i.e point.update(newVal); chart.redraw();